# Community rejects edit with incorrect reason

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, community-user, rejected-edits

Community properly rejected [this edit](https://cs.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/53718) due to edit conflict. The rejection was triggered by [this edit](https://cs.stackexchange.com/revisions/86838/2) by the author.

However, the review message by Community is

> This edit did not correct critical issues with the post - view the revision history to see what should have been changed.

This message would imply a reviewer rejected my edit, but it can be seen this is not the case. No one reviewed the edit as "Reject and Edit", and the rejection took place at the exact same time the author made the edit above.

According to [this rejected edit with the right message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/55309), the expected message would be

> This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit.

Comment: Strange. If the OP is choosing 'Reject and Edit', it should look like this: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9472144

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what happened. They *did* submit the edit through the review task which is why that message was chosen. I'm not sure why their name didn't get recorded there.

Comment: @animuson Was that account involved in an account merge?

Comment: @animuson also no review action for the user in their profile.

Comment: @animuson If that explains the message, then why was it treated as an edit conflict instead? Also, does the edit count towards an edit ban?

Comment: @ShadowtheHedgehogWizard It wasn't. As far as I can tell, the system just failed to record the user's review action into the database for whatever reason. It was processed as a Reject and Edit in every other sense.

Comment: @animuson oh. Nothing in the error logs?

Comment: I don't have access to the error logs. ;) I can only put together what the user did, not what the server failed to do. I was just pointing out that the message chosen was the correct message for what the user did - they selected Reject and Edit in the review task. The bug just lies elsewhere (in the fact that a result wasn't recorded for them).

Comment: @animuson fair enough. If you can poke a dev to look into it, that would be great! :-)